# PHP array_merge result incorrectly on new line

Tags: php

I am trying to array_merge  id’s from one array into another, it’s merging but putting the new values on a new array line:

IDs to be added: `$attachment_ids`

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2620' (length=4)
  1 => string '2621' (length=4)
```

IDs which already exist and will be added to: `$existing_data`

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '2589,2561,2432,2422' (length=19)
```

**result of my array_merge**:

```
$merged_data = array_merge($attachment_ids, $existing_data);
```

is

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2620' (length=4)
  1 => string '2621' (length=4)
  2 => string '2589,2561,2432,2422' (length=19)
```

**My expected result is:**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '2620,2621,2589,2561,2432,2422'
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you need in general, but what about `$merged_data[0] = $existing_data[0] . "," . $attachment_ids[0]`? If these arrays have multiple elements which should be "zipped", write a loop and concat each pair.

Comment: `array_merge` is not supposed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the 1 string with all of the values, you could use `implode()` with the result you have so far...

```
$merged_data = [ implode(",", $merged_data) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() requires 2 arrays. The existing data is all in a string. With explode, this data can be converted into an array. With implode() a list is created after array_merge().

```
$attachment_ids = ['2620','2621'];
$existing_data = ['2589,2561,2432,2422'];

$existing_data = explode(',',$existing_data[0]);

$result = [implode(',',array_merge($attachment_ids,$existing_data))];
//$result: array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "2620,2621,2589,2561,2432,2422" }
```

**Update**

Alternatively, strings can be chained manually.

```
$result = [implode(',',$attachment_ids).','.$existing_data[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly array merge with array_map

```
$result=array_map(null,$array1,$array2);
```